# SOLR 5.0 Share only schema.xml and solrconfig.xml between cores

Tags: solr, solr5

I would like to have several cores in SOLR 5.0 sharing the same schema.xml and solrconfig.xml file but have their own db-data-config.xml file.

I have tried different approaches like 
[Config Sets](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Config+Sets) -
But here I can’t exclude db-data-config.xml.
Changing the path in core.properties. Here SOLR can’t read from parent directory ../schema.xml

The platform is Windows

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

what about choosing one particular core as the canonical one 'coreMain' and then doing:

```
ln -s /path/to/coreMain/conf/schema.xml /path/to/coreA/conf/schema.xml
```

Comment: I read about those symlinks - Maybe this is the only solution. I'm on Windows but it seems like symlinks would work here too. I'll let you know

Comment: oh, I assumed you were on linux, most people deploy Solr on linux. But modern Windows have symlinks too,see mklink